# Action View Template Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

In Development it works just fine, but on Production (Heroku), it breaks with the following Error.

The Error is actually in

```
<%= link_to clip.user.show.name, clip.user.show %>
```

The Error Log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-02T10:24:09.366120+00:00 app[web.1]:     34:
2013-09-02T10:24:09.366120+00:00 app[web.1]:     35:   <p class="clip-uploader pull-left" data-no-turbolink>
2013-09-02T10:24:09.366120+00:00 app[web.1]:     36:     <strong>
2013-09-02T10:24:09.366120+00:00 app[web.1]:     37:       <%= link_to clip.user.show.name, clip.user.show %>
2013-09-02T10:24:09.366120+00:00 app[web.1]:     38:     </strong>
2013-09-02T10:24:09.366120+00:00 app[web.1]:     39:   </p>
2013-09-02T10:24:09.366120+00:00 app[web.1]:     40:
2013-09-02T10:24:09.366120+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/clips/_clip.html.erb:37:in `_app_views_clips__clip_html_erb_
```

Why does this brake on heroku ?

Comment: How do you seed your data in development and in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution was that i had 1 pre existing Clip in my Database from a very early version that had no show attached.

Answer (score 2):

It clearly mentions that clip.user.show is not nil, that mean clip.user is not there in the database. If it can be nil for some values you can try this:-

```
<%if clip.user.show.present?%>
<%= link_to clip.user.show.name, clip.user.show %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: but for an clip to even exist there must be a show. A user can not upload a clip whithout having a show.

Comment: Oh! Then there must be some issue with associations. You are not using it right. Please post your models here.

Comment: Ok i found it, for some reason there where pre existing clips from a previous Version that had clips whithout shows attached :(